# How to set domain in response["set-cookie"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

So the thing is, this code works very well:

```
response["set-cookie"]="cookieName=#{@cookieValue.split.join}"
```

I can set a cookie, with a correct name and content (yes, split.join is correct too). But I need to set a domain too.

My website goes on domain like this: **mysubdomain.mywebsite.com**

But I need to set the cookie for domain mywebsite.com.

If I add it like this, the cookie is just not there:

```
response["set-cookie"]="cookieName=#{@cookieValue.split.join};Path=/;Domain=mywebsite.com"
```

I need to set a cookie with response["set-cookie"] because it is the only method that works for my long string. I tried every method, but I need to use this one.

**So the question is: How can I set a domain by using response["set-cookie"] for setting cookie?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, prefer using an initializer here. Create a new file `config/initializers/cookies.rb`, and put the following code there:

```
options = {
  key: 'your_cookie_name',
  domain: 'your_domain'
}

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, options
```

This will make your cookie-related configuration at one place, although, it's not mandatory. You can still use the `domain` option to specify domain name for your cookie.

Comment: Thank you, but please read the question. I dont want to set domain for my main cookie. Just for that one. And I need to use response["set-cookie"]

Comment: Just like `response`, you can access `cookies` object to set response cookies. `[Read more here`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Comment: Please, read it again. I know cookies["cookieName] etc. I HAVE TO USE response["set-cookie"]

Comment: Can you please be specific? A have read the documentation. If it would answer my question, I would not ask on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make that works. I think Rails have some safety mechanism that prevents this (but it is correct to set cookie for domain from subdomain).

But I was able to do it by javascript:

```
document.cookie = "#{@cookieName}=#{@cookieContent};domain=yourdomain.com"
```

One line of code, works perfectly. Just put it in your view or to separate file and require it in application.js I am on subdomain but finally can set cookie for parent domain.